# How to run code in back end with click on button?What is the function to do this in gtk+?

Tags: c, function, user-interface, callback, gtk

I have created a window in gtk which is displayind info. about my project and it has a next button.now i want that on clicking this " next" button my algorithm should run i.e.

g++ -o output maxflow.cpp should execute .

Can someone tell me function in gtk which does this thing.can it be dine with call_back()

I want to know how to implement this?
I am new to GTK+.

Comment: @ergosys i have implemented application of max. flow graph i.e."project selection problem" using F-F algorithm, so my i/ps are: total no. of projects , profit for each project and prerequisites for projects (prerequisites are other projects only) and o/p is             :max.profit(integer value) and name  of feasible projects that contribute to max. profit.

Comment: @ergosys even name of projects are integer values.

Comment: My question was what do the *terms* o/p, i/p *stand* for, but I'm assuming output and input now.  It's better if you only use abbreviations that are well known, more people will understand your question, and make it more likely that you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard C function called [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) that might be used.

Comment: I have read this.But can u provide with some example or some other solution

Comment: Pileberg  i don't think this is the solution to my problem